# Why use meta description, when we know, if we do not use meta description in a webpage, the Google will show the article text, in SERP?

Tags: google-search, search-results, meta-description

Why use meta description, when we know, if we do not use meta description in a webpage, the Google will show the article text, in SERP?

What role meta description serve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google will only show a different snippet of on-page content as the meta description if they deem it more relevant to the particular search query used.

If no on-page content is deemed as being more relevant for the user's search query, then the meta description will still be used. So therefore, it still definitely serves purpose, as it always has done, but furthermore, encourages website owners to write unique and descriptive meta descriptions that are highly relevant to the page in question which will stand more chance of being displayed in Google's search results.